# Dynamic login/logout navbar

Tags: javascript, node.js, bootstrap-4, navbar, template-engine

I want login button to convert to log out if the user is logged in.
In my index.js file:

```
app.get('/', (request, response) => {

    const authenticated = request.session.authenticated || false;
    // { user: { authenticated: authenticated } }
    response.render('index',authenticated);
    console.log(authenticated);
  });
```

and in my index.pug:

```
`ul.nav.navbar-nav
      li.nav-item
        a.nav-link(href='foods') Foods
      if authenticated  
        li.nav-item
          a.nav-link(href='/logout') Logout
      else      
      li.nav-item.dropdown
        a#navbarDropdownMenuLink.nav-link.dropdown-toggle(href='/registration' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false')
          | Register`
```

I'm not getting any error but it's not working. I don't know how to solve it. Also `console.log(authenticated);` shows the right boolean value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how I solve the issue:
1.

```
let username ='';
```

2.
app.get('/', (request, response) => {

```
    const authenticated = request.session.authenticated || false;
    // { user: { authenticated: authenticated } }
    response.render('index',{ authenticated: authenticated, username: username});  
  });
```

3. in PUG:

   if authenticated 
     p  Welcome #{username}!

4.

```
if authenticated 
    li.nav-item
      a.nav-link(href='/logout') Logout
  if !authenticated        
    li.nav-item.dropdown
      a#navbarDropdownMenuLink.nav-link.dropdown-toggle(href='/registration' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false')
        | Register
```